# How can I get data from a different form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to update and retrieve property data on my Main form from other forms in my Solution.

I am using MS Visual Studio 2022.

I have searched MS Help files. I have searched a Murach book, C# 2015. I have been unable to find any example showing how to do that.